# Porting settings table views from an iOS app to mac

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, uitableview, porting

In the iOS app, I am using grouped UITableViews to handle my settings.  What is likely to be the most sensible way to port this to mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferences in a Mac app are usually presented in a custom-designed Preferences window that can be opened from the menu bar (App Name -> Preferences) or with `Cmd-,`. You can use Cocoa Bindings to the Shared User Defaults Controller to automatically bind controls to user defaults values without writing any code in many circumstances.